# Link to another file in the same svn repository

Tags: svn

Say I want have the following directories and files in a subversion repository:

```
a_dir:
   a_file
   a_shared_file

b_dir:
   b_file
   a_shared_file
```

`a_shared_file` should be the same in both directories; it should work just like a symlink.  So why not use a symlink?  Because `a_dir` and `b_dir` will be checked out separately as working copies, and as far as I understand symlinks in subversion (somewhat abbreviated: they point to locations on the local filesystem), that won't fly.

It seems I could use `svn:externals` for this purpose (since I am able to use svn 1.6+ with file its externals): make `b_dir/a_shared_file` “external” and point it to `a_dir/a_shared_file`.

Is this a good setup?

---

PS: The directories in question contain Latex documents, the shared files would be a class file and some common macro definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `svn:externals` to achieve this. You can factor out the shared files and "import" them in `a_dir` and `b_dir` via `svn:externals`. Or, alternatively, you could put the shared files in either the `a_dir` or `b_dir` repository substructure and point the other to it. The former approach seems the cleanest though.